# ValueError at /post/ No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, api, azure

This is my json:

```
{
  "documents": [
                 {
                 "score": 0.5, 
                 "id": "1"
                  }
               ], 
   "errors":   []
}
```

I want to know how can I fetch 'score' without converting it into the dictionary?Because when I try to use json.loads it give me the following error:

```
ValueError at /post/
No JSON object could be decoded
```

This is the code which I am using.

```
def GetSentiment(documents):
    "Gets the sentiments for a set of documents and returns the 
    information."
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': accessKey}
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(uri)
    body = json.dumps(documents)
    conn.request("POST", path, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    return response.read()

documents = {'documents': [
                        {'id': '1', 'language': 'en', 'text': caption},
             ]}
result = GetSentiment(documents)
resp_dict = json.loads(result)
print resp_dict
score = resp_dict["documents"][0]["score"]
return score
```

Comment: (have improved the code formatting so that its easier to read)

Comment: HI, tell us what you want to do, because maybe you can use another approach

Comment: @mohammedqudah I just want to fetch the value of score because  I want to use that for sentiment analysis.To fetch the score value only i have to use json.loads and thats bugging.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your JSON conversion code and it is fine :

```
>>> result = '{"documents": [{"score": 0.5,"id": "1"}],"errors": []}'
>>> import json
>>> resp_dict = json.loads(result)
>>> score = resp_dict["documents"][0]["score"]
>>> print score
0.5 # success !
```

So your issue must be with the `result` object, which is not what you suggested. Something must be wrong with your `GetSentiment` function.

What does your `print result` line produce ? Also, have you tried using something like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to make your life easier ?